# Возможный метод защиты от Ddos атак или нет

Tags: firewall, ddos, linux

Всем привет, и у меня такой вопрос? как то раз лазил по сайту искал одну статью и наткнулся на способ защиты от Ddosa но забыл сохранить ссылку и статья мне пригодилась бы сейчас: Там было написано что то про метод защиты фронтенд-бэкенд как то так

Возможно ли так сделать: Пример 2 vps сервера на сервер 1 поставить FireWall и настроить его а сервер 2 это под нужды что то будет там работать ну дык вот сделать так чтобы подключение к серверу 2 шло через сервер 1 ну то есть что бы все возможные Ddos атаки, флуд итд фильтровал сервер 1 а отфильтрованные пропускал на сервер 2 возможно есть какой нибудь софт для этого? или похожий метод Метод нужен для Linux ну если я правильно понял то такое возможно или я не так понял даже если на сервер 1 будет идти большая нагрузка пофиг главное чтобы метод был типа этого да я понимаю что он не так эффективен как поставить од в дц итд но для мелких серверов потянет если ошибся сори!

New:Дело в том что у меня не мега компания которой хотят навредить Ddos'om, но когда как сегодня у меня один проект не очень а завтра второй проект конкурирует с множеством да и попыток было много но я их отбил.

И мой хостер ihc.ru (KVM/VPS) и у них нету услуги защиты от Ddos но у них норм vps цена качество мне пока подходят

Дык вот хочу спросить допустим на ihc у меня есть vps и там мои проекты это и есть тот сервер который я хочу защититьИ есть ещё один хостинг в Украине там есть защита от Ddos: http://www.0x2a.com.ua/vps/Можно ли сделать так, сервера оба внешние один в России дугой в Украинесделать чтобы подключение на мой рус сервер шло через мой ua сервер а там на ua сервере уже и будет защита от Ddos мне хватит её!

И ещё как это отразиться на локации рус сервера?

Answer (score 1):

Собственно вот: [Защита от DoS-атак](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDoS#.D0.97.D0.B0.D1.89.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B0_.D0.BE.D1.82_DoS-.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA)

С обычными DoS атаками справиться довольно легко. Достаточно засечь сам факт флуда конкретными пакетами с определённого адреса, и потом их просто отсекать. С DDoS - сложнее. Там атака идёт со множества разных адресов, но всё же отловить можно, если пакет одинаковый. Намного хуже, если пакет меняется - тут уже глубокий анализ нужен.

А абсолютной защиты нет!

ЗЫ: Умные люди вообще внутренние сервера от и-нета отключают, разнося их по разным подсетям. Ну а если это и-нетовский сервак, то будьте готовы! Абсолютной защиты нет! (Хоть я и не люблю слова "нет".)

Comment: Ну это понятно а вы не знаете есть ли такой способ как я написал?Что то wp не помогла

Comment: Ваш способ - это категория "Рассредоточение" из Вики. То же самое я в "ЗЫ" написал. Да, это работает! Но при распределённой атаке с изменяемыми пакетами вы всё равно с этм не справитесь, потому что не сможете отличить полезный пакет от атакующего! Вот так серваки и падают! Что правильно сделать - так это поставить наружу физический роутер, в котоых современных, во всех уже есть отсечка DoS. Большинство из них пашет под тем же Линем, кроме разве что, Cisco, где стоит IOS, но не яблочная, а их собственная. Ну и потом проброс портов сделать.

Comment: Но если у вас VPS , то это забота датацентра! Причём, это у них может быть отдельной услугой.

Comment: Пожалуйста ответьте

Comment: Не хочу вас расстраивать, но это возможно только в локалке. А так у вас оба IP наружу смотрят, и ничего тут не поделать! Как вариант - пробросить тоннель между ними, и основным сделать тот, что UA. Это несколько повысит безопасность, но это тоже не абсолютная защита, потоому, что см. выше!

Comment: На Хабре появилась интересная статья на эту тему: http://habrahabr.ru/post/176119/